# I'm trying to post some data through postman into mongo compass atlas using the following code but get this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

```
     exports.createPost = asyncHandler(async (req,res,next)=>{
    
    //Add user to reqbody
    req.body.user = req.user.id
    const post = await Post.create(req.body)
    res.status(201).json({
        success:true,
        data:post
    })

})
```

Comment: Maybe its `req.body.id` and not `req.user.id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `req.user.id`, req.user - undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but looks like the object `req.user` on what you are trying to access the id prop is `undefined`